# installed upstart-sysv package and now my system loads of to blank screen

Tags: upstart

I hd some dns error thrown for some websites.

As a solution i tried installing upstart-sysv. But now screen loads to blank.

I long press esc n load a kernel then get directed to initramfs console. There i run fsck n it puts me into Xterm terminal but there is no GUI.

I tried deleting the cursed package but it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: please add `lsb_release -r` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:
Enter grub console by pressing ESC on poweron
grub> insmod linux
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot

Then i installed the default systemd-sysv package again and rebooted.

sudo apt-get install systemd-sysv